# Comparing summed values against the master table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Table @t1 is the master table that should have the summed values of table @t2 after an import.

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (
    typ         int,
    total       float
);

insert into @t1 (typ,total) values(1,30.0)
insert into @t1 (typ,total) values(2,70.0)
insert into @t1 (typ,total) values(3,99.9)

DECLARE @t2 TABLE  (
    typ     int,
    value   float
);

insert into @t2 (typ,value) values(1, 10.0)
insert into @t2 (typ,value) values(1, 20.0)
insert into @t2 (typ,value) values(2, 30.0)
insert into @t2 (typ,value) values(2, 40.0)
insert into @t2 (typ,value) values(3, 50.0)


select 
    t1.typ,
    t1.total, 
    t2.typ,
    t2.value,
    case when total = value then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end as Result
    from @t1 t1
left join @t2 t2 on t2.typ = t1.typ
```

Results in:

```
typ|total|typ|value|Result
1  |30   |1  |10   |FALSE
1  |30   |1  |20   |FALSE
2  |70   |2  |30   |FALSE
2  |70   |2  |40   |FALSE
3  |99,9 |3  |50   |FALSE
```

Sure, the Result is always 'FALSE' because t2.value is not summed yet.

My first idea is this:

```
select 
    t1.typ,
    t1.total, 
    -- t2.typ,

    (select sum(t2.value) 
     from @t2 t2 
     where t1.typ = t2.typ
     group by typ) as Summed,

    case when total = (select sum(t2.value) 
                                         from @t2 t2 
                                         where t1.typ = t2.typ
                                         group by typ) then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end as Result
    from @t1 t1
  left join @t2 t2 on t2.typ = t1.typ
```

but I get this

```
typ|total|Summed|Result
1  |30   |30    |TRUE
1  |30   |30    |TRUE
2  |70   |70    |TRUE
2  |70   |70    |TRUE
3  |99,9 |50    |FALSE
```

The correct result has to look so:

```
typ|total|Summed|Result
1  |30   |30    |TRUE
2  |70   |70    |TRUE
3  |99,9 |50    |FALSE
```

I would be glad to get a reply to that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would normally be done with a `left join`:

```
select t1.typ, t1.total, t2.typ, t2.sumvalue,
       (case when t1.total = t2.sumvalue then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end) as Result
from @t1 t1 left join
     (select typ, sum(t2.value) as sumvalue
      from @t2 t2
      group by typ
     ) t2
     on t2.typ = t1.typ;
```

`outer apply` is fine, but this uses standard SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OUTER APPLY` for this:

```
SELECT t1.typ, t1.total, x.Summed,
       CASE 
          WHEN x.Summed = t1.total THEN 'TRUE'
          ELSE 'FALSE'
       END          
FROM @t1 AS t1
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT SUM(value) AS Summed
   FROM @t2 AS t2
   WHERE t1.typ = t2.typ ) AS x
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your case statement to an outer query of a derived table query:

```
select typ, total, 
    case when total = Summed then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end as Result 
from ( 
    select t1.typ,
        t1.total, 
        (select sum(t2.value) 
         from @t2 t2 
         where t1.typ = t2.typ
         group by typ) as Summed     
     from @t1 t1 
) t
```

Comment: This solution is helpfull, too. Thank you Grant N!